# What's the location of package-lock file in React Native Android project?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, package.json, package-lock.json

**Where is the package-lock file located in the project in android studio or in which file?**
because i am getting error. The reason for the error is related to the package file name.

*I guess when I enter the project file, I should first see the package.json file. but it's in the same place in my package-lock.json file.
I can't get an error from terminal about this and run android studio
*

Comment: `package-lock.json` is generated by NPM when you install the dependencies package. There's possibility is not there in your project file when you use YARN for managing dependencies and replaced by `yarn.lock`